# Construct an arraylist inside model

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a model class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "registration_requests")
    class RegistrationRequest(
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Size(min = 2)
    var username: String = "",
    @Size(min = 10, max = 60)
    var password: String = "",
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    var evaluations: String = "",  
    @Transient
    var question: String = "",      
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = 0,
    @DateTimeFormat
    val createdAt: Date = Date.from(Instant.now())
    ) {
        @Transient
        lateinit var evaluationImages: Collection<EvaluationImage>
    }
```

Now I want to initialize the field evaluationImages in a Service

```
var retVal = RegistrationRequest(userDetails.username, userDetails.password, "", "")
retVal.evaluationImages = ArrayList<EvaluationImage>()
```

I am receiving the error "Smart cast to 'kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* = java.util.ArrayList */' is impossible, because 'retVal.evaluationImages' is a complex expression".

My goal further is to add objects of class EvaluationImage to retVal.evaluationImages.
Can anyone please help ?

Comment: At what moment you get the smart cast exception? In the posted code I don't see the place where it might happen.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want `evaluationImages` to look like a mutable list in some scope but as an immutable collection from the outside of the scope. Then, you may do the following

```
class RegistrationRequest(...) {
    internal val _evaluationImages = mutableListOf<String>()
    val evaluationImages: Collection<String> get() = _evaluationImages
}
```

The `internal` modifier allows access to the property from inside the same Gradle project but disallows it from the outside.

Another option is to have two different "views" on your class:

```
interface A {
    val images: MutableList<String>
}

interface B {
    val images: Collection<String>
}

class C : A, B {
    override val images = mutableListOf<String>()
}
```